# How to add element from last loop iteration to list in python?

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
t=['a','b','c']
```

and want to create the output such as:

```
['a']
['a','b']
['a','b','c']
```

I am not sure how to adjust this loop:

```
for i in t:
  print(i)
```

I am not sure how to write the loop to create this appending effect from the last iteration and the current iteration. I hope someone can assist.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the easiest solution:

```
t=['a','b','c']
x=[]
for i in range(len(t)):
    x.append(t[i])
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without nested loop:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
res = []
temp = []
for item in l:
    temp.append(item)
    res.append(temp.copy())
print(res)
```